# SQL Double/Triple the value with SUM and LEFT JOIN ACCESS 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum, left-join

I am getting my result doubled or triple or even x4, x5 depends how many rows I have in the table **ONHAND**, it returns like x2 or x4 or x4 from the correct value, actually the **table ONHAND** has **2 OR MORE rows* because there is a field called "Location" so those 2+ rows of the same subitem are located in different locations, so if I use the aggregate function **SUM()** with this query it returns the wrong total, the **Material requirement should be x1** of SUBITEM, instead x2 SUBITEM (**x2 rows** of SUBITEM in **2** different "Location" but in the same Warehouse in table ONHAND)... This sub-queries is what I have tried until now, but still getting double/triple total of the real values, and I need to use the table ONHAND because there is the Warehouse number.

this is what I am getting (multiplied by x3.)

```
subitem subitemDescription  fecha   TOTAL   Linea   Arearesponsable Areauso PlannerName ItemType    Surtimiento WH
01-0012 ADAPTOR,1/4 BARB X DOLE 30/08/2016  198             Nevarez, Vianey-Tube Bending    MFG     085
```

And this should be the correct TOTAL result

```
SUBITEM SUBITEM DESCRIPTION FECHA   TOTAL   7AM 8AM 9AM 10AM    11AM    12PM    1PM 2PM 3PM 4PM 5PM PLANNER NAME    ITEMTYPE
01-0012 ADAPTOR,1/4 BARB X DOLE 30/08/2016  66  66  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   Nevarez, Vianey-Tube Bending    MFG


    SELECT subquery1.subitem
    ,subquery1.subitemDescription
    ,subquery1.fecha
    ,subquery1.TOTAL
    ,subquery1.Linea
    ,subquery1.Arearesponsable
    ,subquery1.Areauso
    ,subquery1.PlannerName
    ,subquery1.ItemType
    ,subquery1.Surtimiento
    ,subquery1.WH
FROM (
    SELECT b.SUBITEM AS subitem
        ,b.[SUBITEM DESCRIPTION] AS subitemDescription
        ,p.FECHA AS fecha
        ,Sum(p.CANTIDAD * b.[BUILD REQ]) AS TOTAL
        ,pf.Linea AS Linea
        ,pf.Arearesponsable AS Arearesponsable
        ,pf.[Area de Uso] AS AreaUso
        ,b.[PLANNER NAME] AS PlannerName
        ,b.ITEMTYPE AS ItemType
        ,pf.SurtimientoKitKBHeijunka AS Surtimiento
        ,First(oh.Warehouse) AS WH
    FROM (
        (
            (
                PROGRAMA AS p LEFT JOIN TB_BOM AS b ON p.ITEM = b.BOM
                ) LEFT JOIN TB_PFEP AS pf ON b.SUBITEM = pf.[Numero de Parte]
            ) LEFT JOIN TB_KB AS kb ON pf.[Numero de Parte] = kb.[Item number]
        )
    LEFT JOIN TB_ONHAND AS oh ON b.SUBITEM = oh.[Item number]
    GROUP BY b.subitem
        ,b.[SUBITEM DESCRIPTION]
        ,p.FECHA
        ,pf.Linea
        ,pf.Arearesponsable
        ,pf.[Area de Uso]
        ,b.[PLANNER NAME]
        ,b.ITEMTYPE
        ,pf.SurtimientoKitKBHeijunka
        ,oh.Warehouse
    ) AS subquery1
WHERE (subquery1.fecha = [Buscar requerimento de material de la fecha: (mm/dd/aaaa)])
    AND (subquery1.WH = "085")
GROUP BY subquery1.subitem
    ,subquery1.subitemDescription
    ,subquery1.fecha
    ,subquery1.TOTAL
    ,subquery1.Linea
    ,subquery1.Arearesponsable
    ,subquery1.Areauso
    ,subquery1.PlannerName
    ,subquery1.ItemType
    ,subquery1.Surtimiento
    ,subquery1.WH;
```

Comment: You either need to use more conditions (WHERE clauses) or remove columns in your SELECT statement. And all your JOINS will be treated like INNER JOIN. You should move your WHERE clause into your sub query.

Comment: How can I select ONLY 1 row of TB_ONHAND.Warehouse to avoid the quantities multiply x2 x3 x4 xN...